# How to retrieve a misplaced file in Centos 6.2

Tags: linux, file, putty, mv

So I'm rather new to linux and made a dumb mistake. I've moved a file that is needed by a program to a temporary folder called ~ in the / directory. My intention was to move it into the user directory ~ but for some reason, it created... I'm guessing a file called ~. I'm trying to get the file that was mv into this folder or directory. When I try to cd ~ I am moved into the user "~" and not the recently created ~. I have no idea how to access this new type of file. please help! This the file in the root directory that I'm trying to acess as its seen in putty

```
    -rw-r--r--.   1 root root    67 Sep 11 12:10 ~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't moved it to a new folder, you've renamed the file to `~`.
Try `mv '~' foo`. `mv` is used to move and rename files. Next time try `mv foo /home/user/`. That should do the trick.

Comment: You'd better quote that `~` unless you want the shell to expand it.

Comment: That worked! I tried to see if it was a file by opening it in vim but it just opened the user ~ so I was at a loss! Thanks very much!

Comment: I'm now getting an error that says fatal: error processing config file(s). any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Nope. Need more information. If it's a completely different aspect of what you're doing, I'd suggest a new question.

Answer (score 1):

That `ls` output seems to indicate that `~` is not a directory but a regular file.  You should be able to rename it:

```
mv '~' foo
```

And then do whatever you like with `foo`.